# Place advertisement images outside the wordpress content section

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am trying to place two 160x600 px images on a Wordpress site.

```
<img src="PICTURE" width="160px" height="600px">
```

Basically just inserting the code above (the site is http://fodball.dk/).

How do I place advertisements on this site, on the grey background (outside the `<div id="content">`)?

Which Wordpress template file should I edit? I tried almost every file in the template folder, but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to add some details. I am a native English programmer, and I reworded your question to make it easier to understand for other native English programmers.

Your question is good, and I am sure you will ask more good questions in the future. Good luck with your English!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried background property in css?

For example:

```
.bgpic{
    background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg'); 

    /* Optional: */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: No, but the problem is i dont know which file to edit.